Partial derivative with sagemath
I have the function  from which I want to calculate  as well as  and .
I tried using the SymbolicRing of Sagemath with
x = SR.var('x')
y = function('y')
f = sqrt(1+y(x).diff(x,1)^2)

which only allows me to calculate  with f.diff(x).
So I tried with the following sample
x,y = SR.var('x,y')
y = function('y')(x)
y1 = y.diff(x,1)
f(x,y,y1) = sqrt(1+y1^2)
fy1 = f.diff(y1)
fy = f.diff(y)
fxy1 = fy1.diff(x)

which works for calculating  and , but not for . Because fxy1 returns 0 when it should return .
I'd really appreciate any idea. Thanks in advance!
